# How can I access a javascript array with a dynamically created name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a very stripped down example of what I'm trying to do. These arrays are generated with server side code and I can't know which arrays will be there
except that they will always be 'array' followed by a number.

```
var array1 = ['cat','dog','fish','bird'];
var array2 = ['taco','pizza','burger','salad'];
var array3 = ['maple','elm','pine'];
```

The user selects an option from select-1

```
<select id="select-1" onchange="getArray()">
    <option value="1">Pets</option>
    <option value="2">Foods</option>
    <option value="3">Trees</option>
</select>
```

Then I need my function to access the correct array corresponding to the value of select-1. Every option that appears in select-1 will have a corresponding array.

```
function getArray() {
    var x = document.getElementById("select-1").value;

    //how do I access "arrayx"?

    var y = arrayx[0];
}
```

How can I write the function to get a value from the correct array? I need something like

```
arrayname = 'array' + x;
```

but I can't figure out how to get there from here.

Here is a fiddle that's set up to experiment with: http://jsfiddle.net/6yor1kp5/9/

Comment: Put the arrays in an object and then use the `[ ]` operator.

Comment: You should make an array of arrays.

Comment: ... or create a 2D array (which will be almost the same).

Comment: The proper solution is to fix the server-side code.

Comment: Do you have control over that serverside code (to rewrite it in a reasonable way) or is it fixed and you just have to work around it somehow?

Comment: not a good idea but you can use "var y = eval(`array${x}[0]`);"   http://jsfiddle.net/6yor1kp5/11/

Comment: I could change the server-side code yes. I'm not certain what a better way to do that would be.

Comment: `var array = [ ['cat','dog','fish','bird'], ['taco','pizza','burger','salad'], 'maple','elm','pine'] ]; ... array[x]` As the other commenters said, use an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is in the global context in a browser, you can use `window[arrayname]`.

e.g.

```
var y = window["array"+x][0];
```

in your fiddle.

Comment: `var y = this["array"+x][0];` is also an option.

Comment: This worked beautifully.

Comment: To the downvoter, who probably never returns: I did not say it was anything beautiful, but it works for sure, so does the suggestion of @Peteris

Answer (score 2):

You could just follow @Pointy and surround the arrays in another array. In your current situation you'd have to append the arrays into arrayx when you load the arrays from the server.

```
var arrayx = [
    ['cat','dog','fish','bird'],
    ['taco','pizza','burger','salad'],
    ['maple','elm','pine']
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` function for this -

```js
var array1 = ['cat','dog','fish','bird'];
var array2 = ['taco','pizza','burger','salad'];
var array3 = ['maple','elm','pine'];

//if you want to use array1

var array = eval("array" + 1);

console.log(array);
```

But one should *never ever* use `eval`